# How to save multiple UILabels and UIImageViews onto an image into the 'Photos' app

Tags: iphone, ios4

How can I save multiple objects (UIImageViews and UILabels) into an image that will be saved to the users Photos app?

Any help appreciated,

Seb

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UIImageView`, set the background image to whatever `UIImage` you like. Then add subviews, e.g. `UILabel`, `UIImageView`, etc. That done, you can take a screen shot programmatically and save it to photos, email it, message it, etc. If you have trouble with any part of this, then just google for help or, if that fails, post a specific question on SO.